# .htaccess rewriting folder url

Tags: laravel, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a Laravel app that resides in a folder in a Wordpress based website. Name of folder is "artists". It is a database app to list local artists.
I need help rewriting url using .htaccess

Current URL
https://example.ca/artists/artists/name-of-artist

Desired URL
https://example.ca/artists/name-of-artist

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Here is the current .htaccess in the root folder of the Laravel app (artists)

```
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct command you are advised to use is "RedirectMatch 301". Add the following line into ".htaccess" inside public folder of Laravel:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Custom Rule START #
RedirectMatch 301 ^/artists/artists/(.*)$ /artists/$1
#  Custom Rule END  #
```